# difference between leftJoin Yii2 and Raw SQL

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii2

I want to use left join in my code and when I use Yii2 left join the result of code is not correct and it removes some records but when I use Raw SQL left join with given command the result is right:

sql : (it's correct)

```
SELECT tour_date.id as tdid,tour.*, tour_package.*, tour_package.id AS tpid       
FROM tour_date 
LEFT JOIN tour_package ON tour_date.tour_id=tour_package.tour_id 
LEFT JOIN tour ON tour.id=tour_package.tour_id
WHERE tour_package.id
```

yii2 query : (it's wrong)

```
$tourQuery = TourDate::find()
        ->select(['tour_date.id as tdid','tour.*', 'tour_package.*', 'tour_package.id AS tpid'])
        ->leftJoin(TourPackage::tableName(), 'tour_date.tour_id=tour_package.tour_id')
        ->leftJoin(Tour::tableName(), 'tour.id=tour_package.tour_id')
        ->where(['tour_package.id' => $tourPackageId]);
```

Comment: You are missing WHERE in your SQL, Follow this tutorial for better understanding. http://www.devprofessor.com/yii2/how-to-use-sql-joins-in-yii2/

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you mean that you have two representations of the same query you want to execute.. and the former RAW query gives you the desired result, while Yii2-style query not.

Simply analyzing your queries I've noticed that WHERE clause in the former query is incomplete (you do not pass ID param), so it will not filter by `tour_package.id` attribute and you get more rows than expected..

Anyway if that is not the case, you can easily check what kind of query is generated from Yii2 `QueryBuilder` by calling

```
echo $tourQuery->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

So it'll give you the following result:

```
SELECT
  `tour_date`.`id` AS `tdid`, `tour`.*, `tour_package`.*, `tour_package`.`id` AS `tpid`
FROM `tour_date`
  LEFT JOIN `tour_package` ON tour_date.tour_id = tour_package.tour_id
  LEFT JOIN `tour` ON tour.id = tour_package.tour_id
WHERE `tour_package`.`id` = <your_id>
```

..compare this with your raw-query, and you'll find the answer

Comment: tanx about our answer , the problem isn't about "where" in raw sql the result is 20 records but in active record yii2 is 12 , it's work correctly with query builder and I think the active record have options to work correct and i don't know , about ActiveRecord , when tour_date have  some more record from tour_package its return as match tour_package count , but in here we want tour_package to keep all their record , but left joins don't work at this situation

Answer (score 2):

Your  two query are not the same

in RAW sql (first)  you have `WHERE tour_package.id`  where tour_package.id have not condition .

in Yii2 ActiveQuery sintax (second query)  you have `->where(['tour_package.id' => $tourPackageId]);`  where tour_package.id must be equal to $tourPackageId.

so the two query return different result because are different query  ..

assuming the value of  $tourPackageId is 1
You should at least use `WHERE tour_package.id = 1`

*However remeber also that  use of where conidtion in  leftjoin work as a inner join  ..*

so for a correct use of where in left join  you should use the condition inside left join condition and not in explicit where

```
$tourQuery = TourDate::find()
    ->select(['tour_date.id as tdid','tour.*', 'tour_package.*', 'tour_package.id AS tpid'])
    ->leftJoin(TourPackage::tableName(), 'tour_date.tour_id=tour_package.tour_id  
              and tour_package.id = ' . $tourPackageId)
    ->leftJoin(Tour::tableName(), 'tour.id=tour_package.tour_id ')
```

Comment: tanx about our answer , the problem isn't about "where" in raw sql the result is 20 records but in active record yii2 is 12 , it's work correctly with query builder and I think the active record have options to work correct and i don't know , about ActiveRecord , when tour_date have some more record from tour_package its return as match tour_package count , but in here we want tour_package to keep all their record , but left joins don't work at this situation

Comment: Remeber that the use for where in left join work as an inner join .. i have update the answer  with active query code  ..